# How could I generate auto insert function SEAT_NO like A1,A2.... B1,B2 in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

### > I have created below function to get the output like a1,a2.....a12, > b1,b2.....b12,c1......z12.

```
 Create function Fun_Auto_Insert()
returns nchar(3)
as
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Seat_No NCHAR(3) = 'A1' 
    declare @Name CHAR(30) 
    declare @Contact_No INT 
    declare @Row_No INT 
    declare @Row_ID CHAR(1) 
    declare @ASCII_No INT 
    declare @CHAR_ID CHAR 

IF (SELECT count(*) FROM MOVIE_TICKETS) = 0 
    BEGIN 
        RETURN @Seat_No 
    END 
ELSE 
    SELECT @Seat_No= MAX(SEAT_NO) FROM MOVIE_TICKETS 

    SELECT @Row_No=SUBSTRING( @Seat_No,2,LEN(@Seat_No)-1) FROM MOVIE_TICKETS 

IF @Row_No=12 
    BEGIN 
        SET @Row_ID=SUBSTRING(@Seat_No,1,1) 
        --convert to ASCII NO 
        SET @ASCII_No=ASCII(@Row_ID) 
        SET @ASCII_No=@ASCII_No+1 
        --convert to CHAR 
        SET @CHAR_ID=CHAR(@ASCII_No) 
        SET @Row_No=1 
        SET @Seat_No=CONCAT(@CHAR_ID,@Row_No) 
        RETURN @Seat_No 
    END 
ELSE 
    SET @Row_No=@Row_No+1 

SET @Row_ID=SUBSTRING(@Seat_No,1,1) 
SET @Seat_No=CONCAT(@Row_ID,@Row_No) 

RETURN @Seat_No 

END 

GO
```

But unfortunately my logic was failed. Its showing SEAT_NO A10 after A10 like below. But i want A11 after A10.

Can any one please help me out to get the output which i want like a1,a2.....a12, b1,b2.....b12,c1......z12.

```
SEAT_NO CONTACT_NO  NAME
A1      8444        BHARATH
A2      8444        BHARATH
A3      8444        BHARATH
A4      8444        BHARATH
A5      8444        BHARATH
A6      8444        BHARATH
A7      8444        BHARATH
A8      8444        BHARATH
A9      8444        BHARATH
A10     8444        BHARATH
A10     8444        BHARATH
A10     8444        BHARATH
A10     8444        BHARATH
A10     8444        BHARATH
```

Comment: Your `MAX(@Seat_No)` isn't what you think, as it's sorting alphabetically, i.e. A10 is between A1 and A2. If you zero pad it should work 'as-is', otherwise you'll have to handle the two components separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would re-write the whole function and scrap all of this string manipulation, See below:

### Function Definition

```
Create function Fun_Auto_Insert()
returns nchar(3)
as
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Seat_No NCHAR(3);

;WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT Alphas+vals AS SEAT_NO
      ,Alphas 
      ,vals  
FROM (
    select CHAR(number) Alphas
    from master..spt_values
    WHERE number >= 65 and number <= 90
    GROUP BY number) A
              CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4')
                                 ,('5'),('6'),('7'),('8')
                                 ,('9'),('10'),('11'),('12'))C(vals)
)
SELECT TOP 1 @Seat_No = SEAT_NO
FROM CTE C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM MOVIE_TICKETS
                  WHERE C.SEAT_NO = Seat_No)
ORDER BY  Alphas ASC , CAST(vals AS INT) ASC

   RETURN @Seat_No; 
END 
GO
```

### Test

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIE_TICKETS(Seat_No VARCHAR(3))
GO
INSERT INTO MOVIE_TICKETS VALUES ('A2'), ('A10'), ('B2')
GO

SELECT dbo.Fun_Auto_Insert()
GO
```

### Result

```
A1
```

Comment: Thank you vary much, 
Mr. Ali Garu, for the tremendous response with in shot span of time.